# Python: Loop acting on several files and writing new ones

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have the following code which takes the file "University2.csv", 
and writes new csv files "Hours.csv" - "Hours -Stacked.csv" and "Days.csv".

Now  I want the code to be able to loop and run on several files (University3.csv, University4.csv etc.) and produce for each of them "Hours3.csv", "Hours - Stacked3.csv" "Days3.csv", "Hours4.csv" etc.

Here is the code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Importing the csv file into df
df = pd.read_csv('university2.csv', sep=";", skiprows=1)

#Changing datetime
df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'], 
                                               format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

#Set index from column
df = df.set_index('YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS')

#Add Magnetic Magnitude Column
df['magnetic_mag'] = np.sqrt(df['MAGNETIC FIELD X (μT)']**2 + df['MAGNETIC FIELD Y (μT)']**2 + df['MAGNETIC FIELD Z (μT)']**2)

#Copy interesting values
df2 = df[[ 'ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa)',
          'TEMPERATURE (C)', 'magnetic_mag']].copy()

#Hourly Average and Standard Deviation for interesting values 
df3 = df2.resample('H').agg(['mean','std'])
df3.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df3.columns]   

#Daily Average and Standard Deviation for interesting values 
df4 = df2.resample('D').agg(['mean','std'])
df4.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df4.columns] 

#Write to new csv
df3.to_csv('Hours.csv', index=True)  
df4.to_csv('Days.csv', index=True)    

#New csv with stacked hour averages
df5 = pd.read_csv('Hours.csv')
df5['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(df5['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'])  
hour = pd.to_timedelta(df5['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'].dt.hour, unit='H')
df6 = df5.groupby(hour).mean()
df6.to_csv('Hours - stacked.csv', index=True)
```

Can anyone help ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use loop with list `files`. I extract numbers from names of files to `i` and then add them to output names.

Also, you can get `df5` from `df3` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), is not necessary `read_csv` again.

```
import pandas as pd

files = ['university1.csv','university2.csv','university3.csv']

for f in files:
    i = f[-5]
    print i

    #Importing the csv file into df
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";", skiprows=1)

    #Changing datetime
    df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'], 
                                                   format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

    #Set index from column
    df = df.set_index('YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS')

    #Add Magnetic Magnitude Column
    df['magnetic_mag'] = np.sqrt(df['MAGNETIC FIELD X (μT)']**2 + df['MAGNETIC FIELD Y (μT)']**2 + df['MAGNETIC FIELD Z (μT)']**2)

    #Copy interesting values
    df2 = df[[ 'ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa)',
              'TEMPERATURE (C)', 'magnetic_mag']].copy()

    #Hourly Average and Standard Deviation for interesting values 
    df3 = df2.resample('H').agg(['mean','std'])
    df3.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df3.columns]   

    #Daily Average and Standard Deviation for interesting values 
    df4 = df2.resample('D').agg(['mean','std'])
    df4.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df4.columns] 

    #Write to new csv
    df3.to_csv('Hours'+ i + '.csv')  
    df4.to_csv('Day'+ i + 's.csv')    

    #New csv with stacked hour averages
    #df5 = pd.read_csv('Hours.csv')
    #df5['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(df5['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'])  
    df5 = df3.reset_index()
    hour = pd.to_timedelta(df5['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'].dt.hour, unit='H')
    df6 = df5.groupby(hour).mean()
    df6.to_csv('Hours - stacked'+ i + '.csv')
```

EDITED:

More general is Yaron [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36527432/2901002), I uset it and change only `2,3,4` to [`range()`](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/):

```
import pandas as pd

#files = ['university1.csv','university2.csv','university3.csv']
for i in range(1,4):
    print i
    print 'university'+ str(i) + '.csv'

    #Importing the csv file into df
    df = pd.read_csv('university'+ str(i) + '.csv', sep=";", skiprows=1)

    #Changing datetime
    df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'], 
                                                   format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

    #Set index from column
    df = df.set_index('YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS')

    #Add Magnetic Magnitude Column
    df['magnetic_mag'] = np.sqrt(df['MAGNETIC FIELD X (μT)']**2 + df['MAGNETIC FIELD Y (μT)']**2 + df['MAGNETIC FIELD Z (μT)']**2)

    #Copy interesting values
    df2 = df[[ 'ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa)',
              'TEMPERATURE (C)', 'magnetic_mag']].copy()

    #Hourly Average and Standard Deviation for interesting values 
    df3 = df2.resample('H').agg(['mean','std'])
    df3.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df3.columns]   

    #Daily Average and Standard Deviation for interesting values 
    df4 = df2.resample('D').agg(['mean','std'])
    df4.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df4.columns] 

    #Write to new csv
    df3.to_csv('Hours'+ str(i) + '.csv')  
    df4.to_csv('Day'+ str(i) + 's.csv')    

    #New df3 with stacked hour averages
    df5 = df3.reset_index()
    hour = pd.to_timedelta(df5['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'].dt.hour, unit='H')
    df6 = df5.groupby(hour).mean()
    df6.to_csv('Hours - stacked'+ str(i) + '.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do the trick.

It runs a for loop using index (idx) which uses the following values (3,4,5)

It use variable filenames, with the idx as parameter.
e.g.

```
uni_name = "university" + str(idx) + ".csv"
```

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for idx in 3,4,5:
    #Importing the csv file into df
    uni_name = "university" + str(idx) + ".csv"
    df = pd.read_csv(uni_name, sep=";", skiprows=1)

    #Changing datetime
    df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'], 
                                                   format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

    #Set index from column
    df = df.set_index('YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS')

    #Add Magnetic Magnitude Column
    df['magnetic_mag'] = np.sqrt(df['MAGNETIC FIELD X (μT)']**2 + df['MAGNETIC FIELD Y (μT)']**2 + df['MAGNETIC FIELD Z (μT)']**2)

    #Copy interesting values
    df2 = df[[ 'ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa)',
              'TEMPERATURE (C)', 'magnetic_mag']].copy()

    #Hourly Average and Standard Deviation for interesting values 
    df3 = df2.resample('H').agg(['mean','std'])
    df3.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df3.columns]   

    #Daily Average and Standard Deviation for interesting values 
    df4 = df2.resample('D').agg(['mean','std'])
    df4.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df4.columns] 

    #Write to new csv
    hours = "Hours" + str(idx) + ".csv"
    days = "Days" + str(idx) + ".csv"

    df3.to_csv(hours, index=True)  
    df4.to_csv(days, index=True)    

    #New csv with stacked hour averages
    df5 = pd.read_csv('Hours.csv')
    df5['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(df5['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'])  
    hour = pd.to_timedelta(df5['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'].dt.hour, unit='H')
    df6 = df5.groupby(hour).mean()
    hours_st = "Hours - stacked" + str(idx) + ".csv"
    df6.to_csv('Hours - stacked.csv', index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you !! That was the idea !

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [sys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) module

And this is how you can use it by calling the python program as `prog.py one.csv two.csv 1..n.csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

for input in sys.argv:
    process(input)

def process(input):
    #Importing the csv file into df
    df = pd.read_csv(input, sep=";", skiprows=1)

    #Changing datetime
    df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'], 
                                               format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

    #Set index from column
    df = df.set_index('YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS')

    #Add Magnetic Magnitude Column
    df['magnetic_mag'] = np.sqrt(df['MAGNETIC FIELD X (μT)']**2 + df['MAGNETIC FIELD Y (μT)']**2 + df['MAGNETIC FIELD Z (μT)']**2)

    #Copy interesting values
    df2 = df[[ 'ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa)',
          'TEMPERATURE (C)', 'magnetic_mag']].copy()

    #Hourly Average and Standard Deviation for interesting values 
    df3 = df2.resample('H').agg(['mean','std'])
    df3.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df3.columns]   

    #Daily Average and Standard Deviation for interesting values 
    df4 = df2.resample('D').agg(['mean','std'])
    df4.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df4.columns] 

    #Write to new csv
    hours = input[:-4]+'_Hours.csv'
    df3.to_csv(hours, index=True)  
    df4.to_csv(input[:-4]+'_Days.csv', index=True)    

    #New csv with stacked hour averages
    df5 = pd.read_csv(hours)
    df5['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(df5['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'])  
    hour = pd.to_timedelta(df5['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'].dt.hour, unit='H')
    df6 = df5.groupby(hour).mean()
    df6.to_csv(input[:-4]+'_Hours - stacked.csv', index=True)
```